# Azure AD: local account users "Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set."

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to have an ability to reset the password using email but seems like it's impossible to add it via Graph API.  I get `Property 'mail' is read-only and cannot be set.` error every time. 
That's how I create a user:

```
{
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "somename",
  "mailNickname": "somenickname",
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "goGOhey22",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  },
  "mail" : "ydw89488@tqoai.com",
  "mobile": "(111) 111-1111",
  "creationType": "LocalAccount",
  "signInNames": [
    {
      "type": "userName",
      "value": "heyTEst12"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I am trying to add email as "otherMails" property I get an AADB2C90161 error on 3rd step on Forgot Password step.
All works well only If I manually add email through AAD interface.
Any idea why?

Comment: If you look at the [user object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) you will see that `mail` is a property that can only be set on user creation, and is used for the SMTP address for that user. The dynamic email property you want is `otherMails`, which can also be updated. However you issues seems more related to reset password flow. Can you share more details on that error? Add screenshots, etc?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi when I add email as the otherMails property I am able to get a verification code on this email on first reset password step, but on the second step when I pressing "Next" I see an error: https://www.screencast.com/t/1XGtraIp. 
Google said me that I need to setup email property for a user for avoiding this error but how can I do that via Graph API?